# Batch File Set Variable not working

Tags: variables, batch-file, set

I'm doing some simple setting of a variable in a BAT file. It's not setting the variable. There aren't any odd constructs, it's simple variable substitution using the same variable name. I reduced the BAT file to a simple proof of concept version:

```
set TESTVAR = "No Value"
ECHO var = %TESTVAR%
set TESTVAR = ""
ECHO var = %TESTVAR%
set TESTVAR = "New value"
ECHO var = %TESTVAR%
```

And the output shows that none of the SET commands seem to be working. What the heck am I missing here. I've been writing BAT files for years and I've never seen this before. Here's the output from running this test:

```
C:\Users\rs02130\Desktop>test

C:\Users\rs02130\Desktop>set TESTVAR = "No Value"

C:\Users\rs02130\Desktop>ECHO var =
var =

C:\Users\rs02130\Desktop>set TESTVAR = ""

C:\Users\rs02130\Desktop>ECHO var =
var =

C:\Users\rs02130\Desktop>set TESTVAR = "New value"

C:\Users\rs02130\Desktop>ECHO var =
var =
C:\Users\rs02130\Desktop>
```

I expect the first and third ECHO commands to display the values "No Value" and "New value". What the heck is going on?

Comment: No one said, that you should put spaces between Testvar and the equal sign.

Comment: Not sure about this, but maybe you need to `EnableDelayedExpansion`

Comment: Spaces around the equal signs <sigh>... I knew it was something really dumb. Thanks.

Comment: I just did the same darn thing. How dumb.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The problem is the spaces around the equal sign.  This should do what you want.

```
set TESTVAR="No Value"
ECHO var = %TESTVAR%
set TESTVAR=""
ECHO var = %TESTVAR%
set TESTVAR="New value"
ECHO var = %TESTVAR%
```