# Windows CMD Set variable with space in variable name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

To make my batch file readable, I tried to align the `SET` statements as below

```
SET SVN_URL           = http://server.test.com
SET SVN_USER_NAME     = foo
SET SVN_USER_PASSWORD = pass
```

How ever when I try to echo `%SVN_URL%` I got nothing. I found that the variable names could have spaces https://ss64.com/nt/set.html

So my variable will be `%SVN_URL           %` (with spaces)

Is it any way to fix it ?!

Comment: Ahm... what about removing the spaces??

Comment: When using the `set` command, you really want to avoid spaces around the `=` entirely; always format your `set` statements as `set varname=value` and add comments (`rem` statements) if you want readable documentation.

Comment: There is no problem with spaces in front of the var name if you need to align the equal sign that heftily ;-) To avoid inadvertant leading/trailing spaces in varname or content I'd double quote them `Set "SVN_URL=http://server.test.com"`

Comment: @LotPings I tried `SET  "SVN_URL         =       http://server.test.com"` but still the `echo %SVN_URL%` is not defined. Did I get you wrong ?!

Comment: Yes, in my command there are no spaces around the equal sign. The number of spaces following set don't matter `Set         "SVN_URL=http://server.test.com"` but are removed by this site ;-)

Comment: Dear @LotPings can you please send it as answer I could not get it work !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch File Set Variable not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448522/batch-file-set-variable-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that spaces are significant on **both** sides of the `set`

This would set your values (noting that each value will contain a leading space)

```
SET           SVN_URL= http://server.test.com
SET     SVN_USER_NAME= foo
SET SVN_USER_PASSWORD= pass
```

or

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims== " %%a in (SVN_URL           = http://server.test.com) do set "%%a=%%b"
for /f "tokens=1*delims== " %%a in (SET SVN_USER_NAME     = foo) do set "%%a=%%b"
for /f "tokens=1*delims== " %%a in (SET SVN_USER_PASSWORD = pass) do set "%%a=%%b"
```

or

```
call :setv SVN_URL           = http://server.test.com
call :setv SVN_USER_NAME     = foo
call :setv SVN_USER_PASSWORD = pass

...
:setv
set "%~1=%~2"
goto :eof
```

noting that with this last, you may need to enclose the value in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Magoo's first version you can align the equal signs to fit your aestetics or whatever.

```
SET           "SVN_URL=http://server.test.com"
SET     "SVN_USER_NAME=foo"
SET "SVN_USER_PASSWORD=pass"
```

In a comment excessive white space is removed, so I couldn't demonstrate.