# How do you add a variable to a string in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables, variable-assignment

I can't seem to find how to do this simple task, and this is probably answered.

How does one add a string to a variable? such as `set "FileNameAndPCName = Locker\` and add `%COMPUTERNAME%"` to the variable so it would become like, `"Locker/Bill"`?

Code:

```
@echo off
set FileNameAndPCName="Locker\" + "%COMPUTERNAME%"
echo %FileNameAndPCName%
pause
```

Comment: remove spaces around `=`. They're significant in the `set` command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch File Set Variable not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448522/batch-file-set-variable-not-working)

Comment: Sadly its not (I think), if I share you the entire code are you able to see what the problem is?

Comment: of course no one can help you if you don't show a [mcve]

Comment: no. questions should be self-contained. No one will click on an external link just to read the code

Comment: Read the new edit

Comment: you already have an answer to the question, but to add to it. The only time `+` is used is when you use `set /a` which is for numerical evaluation. i.e `set /a num=1+2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operations in batch is already string manipulation, therefore you don't need and can't use `+` to concatenate strings. Just type the whole string like this

```
set "FileNameAndPCName=Locker\%COMPUTERNAME%"
```

`set FileNameAndPCName="Locker\" + "%COMPUTERNAME%"` will set the variable `%FileNameAndPCName%` to `"Locker\" + "%COMPUTERNAME%"` literally (after substituting `%COMPUTERNAME%`. Quotes are not special in the `set` command. And it's also recommended to use the `set "var=value"` variant instead of `set var=value` to avoid unexpected trailing spaces at the end